# How to scroll through intellisense overloads with keyboard in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

This has always bugged me.  In the image below, I just typed the opening `(` after `builder.RequireAssertion`.  Autocomplete filled in the closing `)` for me.  I got the popup with the overloads, and also the popup for the autocomplete.

Here, if I press up or down arrows, it scrolls me through the autocomplete options.  But I want to use the arrows to scroll through the `1 of 2` overloads.  Is that possible?  Are there different keys I should be using for that?  Currently I have to go to the mouse to click through them.

I'm using VS2022.

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the cursor after the first bracket `(` and press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Space`. Then use the arrow keys to navigate.

[image]